# Use latest launch template version in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code, aws-auto-scaling

I am writing a cloudformation (cf) template to provision an auto-scaling group, I prepared the launch template ahead of time and want to use the latest version.

I am getting the LaunchTemplateId as a parameter but I am not sure how to use the latest lunch template version.

my cf template looks like this:

```
--- 
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Create Auto Scaling Group with 2 min, 2 desired, 4 max
Parameters:
...
  TemplateID: 
    Description: Lunch Template for ASG EC2s 
    Type: String
    Default: lt-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Resources:  
  ASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
...
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: !Ref TemplateID
        Version: !GetAtt 
          - !Ref TemplateID
          - LatestVersionNumber
...
```

but I always get this linting error when I run taskcat for testing:

> [ERROR  ] : Linting detected issues in: /Users/zaidafaneh/Desktop/RealBlocks/repos/cloudformation-temaplates/templates/saas/asg.yml

> [ERROR  ] :     line 23 [1010] [GetAtt validation of parameters] Invalid GetAtt TemplateID.LatestVersionNumber for resource ASG

I am thinking about using Lambda Custom Resource as a workaround but I feel it's too much.
is there any way to do this through cloudformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!GetAtt` only works for resources created in the template, you can't use it to get a property for a parameter.

To achieve the desired workflow, you'll have to either:

1. Create the launch template in the same template (then you can use `!GetAtt` as you are doing now)
2. Pass in the version number as an additional parameter.

If the launch template was created with another CloudFormation template, then there is a third option:

3. Export the launch template resource from the other template and import it in your template; then you'll be able to use `!GetAtt`

Comment: According to the documentation [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-autoscaling-autoscalinggroup-launchtemplatespecification.html#cfn-autoscaling-autoscalinggroup-launchtemplatespecification-version) this is not possible: Specifying $Latest or $Default for the template version number is not supported. However, you can specify LatestVersionNumber or DefaultVersionNumber using the Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function. For more information, see Fn::GetAtt.

Comment: @ZaidAfaneh yes, that's right

Comment: I tried it also and didn't work with the same message mentioned in the documentation

Comment: @ZaidAfaneh please read my updated answer

Comment: I don't want to change my lunch template, is it even a best practice to create a different template each time the cf template is updated?

I though about Option 2 but want to make sure if there is a way to always use the latest.

Comment: *I don't want to change anything on my template*.. then you won't be able to get this working.

Comment: @ZaidAfaneh option 2 is the best one I think; how are you invoking the cloudformation template? it should be straightforward to run a CLI command to fetch the latest version of the launch template and feed that in when launching the stack

Comment: @ZaidAfaneh no, that's not supported. is the launch template created by another CloudFormation stack by any chance?

Comment: Yes through CLI. I believe fetching the version number first and feeding it to the create-stack command will do the job for me. 

Thank you

Comment: @ZaidAfaneh in which case I've now added a third option

Comment: No, it was manually created. 
if it was created by another stack I would export the value of the latest version from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit too late to the question, but after fiddling with CloudFormation I've found out that you can just specify a parameter for the Version attribute like so:

```
Parameters:
  LaunchTemplateVersion:
    Type: String
    Description: Version number of the launch template

Resources:
  EC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplate:
        LaunchTemplateId: # Replace with your launch template ID
        Version: !Ref LaunchTemplateVersion
```

and the nice part is that you don't even need to specify a value for `LaunchTemplateVersion`! AWS seems to just use the latest (or default) version of your EC2 template. I cannot find the resource to back this answer up, so this is a just 'trust me bro' solution.

EDIT: to use this within the AWS cli, do:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name #YOUR_STACK_NAME# --template-url #YOUR_TEMPLATE# --parameters ParameterKey="LaunchTemplateVersion",ParameterValue=
```

EDIT2: aws uses the default version, not the latest version. So remember to change that in your aws configuration.